# How can I get rid of the white bar on the top of my page?

Tags: html, css

How can I move the Navbar and the logo inside the background image without getting this white bar on the top? I am new to html and css but have some basic knowledge. I have checked other similar questions but those couldn't help me either. I want to keep the parallax effect but also have a navigation bar at the top. That could be the reason why the other questions couldn't help me out, so I am asking a new question here. Thanks in advance.

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Monument Extended", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: inherit;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 80px;
}

header h2 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size:20px;
}

header,
header:before {
    background: 50% 50% / cover;
}

header::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    background: url(IMG_3497.JPG);
    background-size: cover;
    transform-origin: center center 0;
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    z-index: -1;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100vh;
    background: black;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 40px;
    color: grey;
}

.navbar {
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 35px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  width: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Think Tank</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="navbar">
<img src="officialipng.png" class="logo">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ratgeber</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Über uns</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

        <div class="container">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores harum veritatis
                nemo magni odio reprehenderit atque, esse animi porro suscipit vero nobis modi quis.
                Exercitationem quasi beatae, assumenda officia illum sunt. Cum voluptas maiores
                vitae eius hic inventore deleniti placeat perferendis quam ut nostrum maxime optio
                voluptatibus ab laboriosam, quia consectetur atque minus? Adipisci amet aut sint
                voluptates delectus aperiam? Veniam ab illum enim in libero nihil culpa explicabo
                perspiciatis veritatis non repellendus architecto excepturi nostrum porro voluptatem
                aperiam animi asperiores, a voluptatibus temporibus minima voluptas ipsa! Recusandae
                nostrum, aut, voluptates est error iusto, eaque excepturi soluta quas maiores amet.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum perferendis error
                debitis deleniti obcaecati nisi dignissimos doloribus omnis incidunt neque.
                Aspernatur, odit. Natus, porro adipisci corporis perspiciatis aspernatur illum
                repellendus vitae explicabo, ex reiciendis molestiae id dicta quos repudiandae at.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores harum veritatis
                nemo magni odio reprehenderit atque, esse animi porro suscipit vero nobis modi quis.
                Exercitationem quasi beatae, assumenda officia illum sunt. Cum voluptas maiores
                vitae eius hic inventore deleniti placeat perferendis quam ut nostrum maxime optio
                voluptatibus ab laboriosam, quia consectetur atque minus? Adipisci amet aut sint
                voluptates delectus aperiam? Veniam ab illum enim in libero nihil culpa explicabo
                perspiciatis veritatis non repellendus architecto excepturi nostrum porro voluptatem
                aperiam animi asperiores, a voluptatibus temporibus minima voluptas ipsa! Recusandae
                nostrum, aut, voluptates est error iusto, eaque excepturi soluta quas maiores amet.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum perferendis error
                debitis deleniti obcaecati nisi dignissimos doloribus omnis incidunt neque.
                Aspernatur, odit. Natus, porro adipisci corporis perspiciatis aspernatur illum
                repellendus vitae explicabo, ex reiciendis molestiae id dicta quos repudiandae at.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores harum veritatis
                nemo magni odio reprehenderit atque, esse animi porro suscipit vero nobis modi quis.
                Exercitationem quasi beatae, assumenda officia illum sunt. Cum voluptas maiores
                vitae eius hic inventore deleniti placeat perferendis quam ut nostrum maxime optio
                voluptatibus ab laboriosam, quia consectetur atque minus? Adipisci amet aut sint
                voluptates delectus aperiam? Veniam ab illum enim in libero nihil culpa explicabo
                perspiciatis veritatis non repellendus architecto excepturi nostrum porro voluptatem
                aperiam animi asperiores, a voluptatibus temporibus minima voluptas ipsa! Recusandae
                nostrum, aut, voluptates est error iusto, eaque excepturi soluta quas maiores amet.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum perferendis error
                debitis deleniti obcaecati nisi dignissimos doloribus omnis incidunt neque.
                Aspernatur, odit. Natus, porro adipisci corporis perspiciatis aspernatur illum
                repellendus vitae explicabo, ex reiciendis molestiae id dicta quos repudiandae at.
            </p>
        </div>
        <header>
            <h1>Think Tank</h1>
            <h2>Finanzen • Business • Mindset</h2>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Hrn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your padding to 0 for the NavBar class in your CSS. It will remove the white space on the top. To have a better understanding, I recommend you inspect your browser and check the layout of your components.

Answer (score 0):

you had a lot going on in your html and css so I wrote something that should help you get started.  It uses a good bit of flexbox to move everything in to position but I think you should be able to edit it from here.

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Monument Extended", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

h1, h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1200) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;

}

header div {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}


nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.container {
    background: black;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 40px;
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Think Tank</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <header>
        <nav>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120" class="logo">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ratgeber</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Über uns</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div>
          <h1>Think Tank</h1>
          <h2>Finanzen • Business • Mindset</h2>
        </div>
        
      </header>
        <div class="container">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores harum veritatis
                nemo magni odio reprehenderit atque, esse animi porro suscipit vero nobis modi quis.
                Exercitationem quasi beatae, assumenda officia illum sunt. Cum voluptas maiores
                vitae eius hic inventore deleniti placeat perferendis quam ut nostrum maxime optio
                voluptatibus ab laboriosam, quia consectetur atque minus? Adipisci amet aut sint
                voluptates delectus aperiam? Veniam ab illum enim in libero nihil culpa explicabo
                perspiciatis veritatis non repellendus architecto excepturi nostrum porro voluptatem
                aperiam animi asperiores, a voluptatibus temporibus minima voluptas ipsa! Recusandae
                nostrum, aut, voluptates est error iusto, eaque excepturi soluta quas maiores amet.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum perferendis error
                debitis deleniti obcaecati nisi dignissimos doloribus omnis incidunt neque.
                Aspernatur, odit. Natus, porro adipisci corporis perspiciatis aspernatur illum
                repellendus vitae explicabo, ex reiciendis molestiae id dicta quos repudiandae at.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores harum veritatis
                nemo magni odio reprehenderit atque, esse animi porro suscipit vero nobis modi quis.
                Exercitationem quasi beatae, assumenda officia illum sunt. Cum voluptas maiores
                vitae eius hic inventore deleniti placeat perferendis quam ut nostrum maxime optio
                voluptatibus ab laboriosam, quia consectetur atque minus? Adipisci amet aut sint
                voluptates delectus aperiam? Veniam ab illum enim in libero nihil culpa explicabo
                perspiciatis veritatis non repellendus architecto excepturi nostrum porro voluptatem
                aperiam animi asperiores, a voluptatibus temporibus minima voluptas ipsa! Recusandae
                nostrum, aut, voluptates est error iusto, eaque excepturi soluta quas maiores amet.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum perferendis error
                debitis deleniti obcaecati nisi dignissimos doloribus omnis incidunt neque.
                Aspernatur, odit. Natus, porro adipisci corporis perspiciatis aspernatur illum
                repellendus vitae explicabo, ex reiciendis molestiae id dicta quos repudiandae at.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores harum veritatis
                nemo magni odio reprehenderit atque, esse animi porro suscipit vero nobis modi quis.
                Exercitationem quasi beatae, assumenda officia illum sunt. Cum voluptas maiores
                vitae eius hic inventore deleniti placeat perferendis quam ut nostrum maxime optio
                voluptatibus ab laboriosam, quia consectetur atque minus? Adipisci amet aut sint
                voluptates delectus aperiam? Veniam ab illum enim in libero nihil culpa explicabo
                perspiciatis veritatis non repellendus architecto excepturi nostrum porro voluptatem
                aperiam animi asperiores, a voluptatibus temporibus minima voluptas ipsa! Recusandae
                nostrum, aut, voluptates est error iusto, eaque excepturi soluta quas maiores amet.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum perferendis error
                debitis deleniti obcaecati nisi dignissimos doloribus omnis incidunt neque.
                Aspernatur, odit. Natus, porro adipisci corporis perspiciatis aspernatur illum
                repellendus vitae explicabo, ex reiciendis molestiae id dicta quos repudiandae at.
            </p>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
Expand snippet
```